# Copy input value from one input to second input in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
function copyInputsCompanyInvoices() {
                document.querySelector('input[name="company_invoice_company_name]').value = document.querySelector('input[name="company_info[name]"]').value;
            }
```

and this work fine.
I want change it to jQuery.
I write this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $(".copyInputsToInvoice").click(function(){ $('input[name="company_invoice_company_name]').val($('input[name="company_info[name]"]').val());
            });
        });
```

but it's not working. How can I repair it?

Comment: There is a typo. You are missing quote in attribute selector. Should be cument).ready(function() {
           `$(".copyInputsToInvoice").click(function(){ $('input[name="company_invoice_company_name"]').val($('input[name="company_info[name]"]').val());
            });`

Comment: Are you sure the function(in javascript) is being called `onclick`? 
I think `onchange` or `oninput` should solve your problem.

Comment: Please add your html also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot : ( " )

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".copyInputsToInvoice").click(function(){        
        $('input[name="company_invoice_company_name"]').val($('input[name="company_info[name]"]').val());
    });
});
```

or u can use this; **keyup event**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="company_info[name]"]').keyup(function(){ 
        $('input[name="company_invoice_company_name"]').val($('input[name="company_info[name]"]').val());
    });
});
```